# Convert from int to char in C with cutoff

Tags: c

I need to convert int to unsigned char in C. If int > 255  char will be 255, and if in < 0 char will be 0. Otherwise char is equal to int. How do I do that in C?

I tried:

```
int i;
unsigned char c;
c = (unsigned char) i;
```

but it hasn't worked yet (it wraps around, i.e. c = i % 256).

Comment: You want to *saturate* an `int` to a `char`? Some processors have instructions for that.

Comment: `char` has implementation defined signed-ness. Don't ask for `char` if you mean `unsigned char` (which is the correct type to use, of course).

Answer (score 5):

Just code what you want.

```
unsigned char convert(int j)
{
    if (j >= 255) return 255;
    if (j < 0) return 0;
    return (unsigned char) j;
}
```

This may perform better (on my machine, 6 instructions, no branches), especially if most values are in the range of 0-255:

```
unsigned char convert(int j)
{
    unsigned char j2 = (unsigned char) j;
    if (j == j2) return j2;
    return (j < 0) ? 0 : 255;
}
```

Comment: That works, but are there any casting using bit operations? Or memcpy?

Comment: @DzungNguyen Is there some reason you want to make things less efficient and harder to understand?

Comment: @DzungNguyen you're asking to _change_ the value, based on certain circumstances. Casting and memcpy do not do that.

Comment: This has more instructions. And I'm just curious if there's another way to do this.

Comment: @DzungNguyen If it has more instructions, that's only because it can't be optimized. If it can't be optimized, it can't be optimized. Write what you mean as clearly as you can, and if the compiler can optimize it, it will.

Comment: @DzungNguyen: Write readable and understandable code. Leave optimisations first to the compiler. A modern compiler is often smarter than most humans. If**f** that really proves to be too slow in benchmarks, profile, then optimise the hotspots.

Comment: Not sure, but best to use a pattern the compiler does recognise and possibly replaces with a special saturate instruction. Also the conversion of not fitting integer values to a smaller unsigned type is implementation defined.

Comment: Any particular reason for `>= 255` vs OP's `> 255`?  I would think it is the same code either way.

Comment: @Olaf "the conversion of not fitting integer values to a smaller unsigned type is implementation defined."  Is not is well define per "... value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value... "? C11 §6.3.1.3 2

Comment: @chux: My bad, I tend to confuse this with the other direction. Anyway, it was just a minor hint; most (all?) platforms just truncate for both.

Comment: For 255, it doesn't seem to make any difference. For 0, `<0` produced better code for some reason.